# How to add an item between each item in a list

Tags: scheme

I would like an `intersperse` function that inserts an item between each item in an existing list. For example:

```lisp
(intersperse '? '(a b c d))
;; Returns: `(a ? b ? c ? d)
```

Here is an implementation:

```lisp
(define (intersperse separator ls)
  (if (null? ls)
    ls
    (let* ((reversed-ls (reverse ls))
           (last (car reversed-ls))  ; Last item in ls.
           (butlast (reverse (cdr reversed-ls))))  ; ls, but without the last item.
      (append (apply append
                     (map (lambda (x)
                            (list x separator))
                          butlast))
              (list last)))))
```

The implementation appears to function correctly. However, it looks rather inefficient. The list is reversed twice. Is there a better way to implement the `intersperse` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible to write a shorter version in terms of list primitives and doing a single pass over the input list, like this:

```
(define (intersperse separator ls)
  (if (or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls)))
      ls
      (cons (car ls)
            (cons separator
                  (intersperse separator (cdr ls))))))
```

The trick is to apply the standard template for recursively consuming a list and building an output list (see the book: "How to Design Programs".) It works as expected:

```
(intersperse '? '())
=> '()

(intersperse '? '(a))
=> '(a)

(intersperse '? '(a b))
=> '(a ? b)

(intersperse '? '(a b c))
=> '(a ? b ? c)

(intersperse '? '(a b c d))
=> '(a ? b ? c ? d)
```